# save single record from mysql query to variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a table where is a row called ID and I want to save that ID to variable that I can use later on the same PHP file. How can I do it?

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * auto_matkat");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
  $IND = $row['IND'];
  echo $IND;
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: It depends on how you fetch your row/rows. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: Presumably you already have *some* database code. Since there are many different ways to connect to a database, if you expect code as an answer, you will at least have to show us some of your current code. Otherwise any answer may be completely useless.

Comment: I have updated the code to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case CoDe ADDict's code is a bit complex for you this one may be a bit simpler:

```
mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die(mysql_error());
     $query="SELECT * FROM auto_matkat";
$result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
$i=0;
while($i<$num){
$id[$id]=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
}
echo $id;
```

Here is a great website for beginners learning PHP & MySQL connections: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: is it possible to save the record to variable if I don't know what the id is? for example if I have a query like `select * from table where number =1`. How can i select ID from that query?

Comment: Just made a little update to put the data in an array and the connection and SQL values to match yours.

Comment: @user1423276 if you select only one table entry for example the entry with an id of 1 then only that id would be inserted into the array just change the syntax to what you have above. If you are trying to save all the data from the entry (multiple fields) than just copy what I did for ID in the while loop and change it to what you need.

Comment: @user1423276 if you visit part 4 of the link I mentioned above it gives you step by step instructions on how to select the data. It also explains each line very well in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM IDTable");
$ID="0";

//iterate the result set
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $ID=$row[0] 
  //echo here
  echo "MyID".$ID;
}
  //OR echo here
  //echo "MyID".$ID;
```